# How to ensure applications only open on a single desktop environment in windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, window-manager

I like to keep two desktop environments on my Windows 10 machine. However, I prefer these to work mostly independent of each other. I would like the apps to not be spread across both desktops. Let me show you what I mean.

Here is the taskbar on Desktop 1:

[image]

Now if I go to Desktop 2 using the task view button shown here:[image]

The taskbar also looks like this:

[image]

I would like it to have no apps open at the bottom in Desktop 2. I find it annoying that when I open Chrome now on Desktop 2 it sends me over to Desktop 1. Do you know how to make the two desktops operate mostly independent of each other?

Comment: Your question is based on a misconception. There is nothing to "sync". You merely have two views onto the same user account. Exactly as if you had dual displays, but without the extra hardware.

Comment: I interpreted Desktop 1 and 2 as two computers. My confusion based on question wording so I deleted my post as it does not apply. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I don't have this behavior at all (I just checked).  If I am on `Desktop 2` and I open Chrome, it only shows on `Desktop 2` (and only taskbar on Desktop 2).  Perhaps I am not understanding the problem.. or perhaps we have different settings.  I am running 20H2

Comment: Windows 10 used to behave the way I wanted. I think a setting I tweaked or an update has changed this. I simply want the desktops to be more independent of each other. If I open e.g. Notepad on Desktop 1, I want it to not appear in the taskbar of Desktop 2. (This is how my PC used to behave about a week ago.)

Comment: Oh, and well written question with visual guides. (+1)

Comment: I think the SYNC wording should be removed as syncing does not really apply to Windows Desktop variations - at least not here.

Comment: I have rephrased the title to hopefully make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found the solution. I simply needed to toggle the setting found here:

[image]